# Sending email through cron with Django

Tags: python, django, cron

I want to set up a cron job that sends a daily email to all users in my Django project.

I registered the following bash script with cron tab:

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/app"
export PYTHONPATH
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.prod

python /path/to/app/cron.py
```

In `cron.py` the email is sent in:

```
email = mail.EmailMessage(
    'subject'
    text,
    settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
    [user.email]
)
messages.append(email)

connection = mail.get_connection()
connection.open()
connection.send_messages(messages)
connection.close()
```

The cronjob is executed correctly. However, the Postfix logs revealed that wrong email addresses are used as from and to emails. In both cases it's user-who-registered-cronjob@host-regisered-in-postfix. Is there anything, I'm missing here when I set the environment?

Thanks for your help.